# CMake for Visual Studio project with source in parent directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake

I have to make a CMakeLists.txt file for a HelloWorld-project in C++ that has the following file structure:

- /HW1/CMakeLists.txt
- /HW1/build/project
- /HW1/HelloWorld.cpp

The project should be a Visual Studio 2015 Project. So this is what I did:

1. I created a HelloWorld.cpp-file containing the correct source code.
2. I made a CMakeLists.txt-file with the following contents:

> ```
> cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.3)
> project (HW1)
> add_executable(HW1 HelloWorld.cxx)
> ```

3. I made the folder /build manually and executed the following command line commands:

> ```
> cd build
> cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 2015 Win64"
> ```

Now it creates the Visual Studio-project, but it cannot find the source files. And this project should also be created without using the command line commands. I read some things saying it's not possible to include a generator in the CMakeLists.txt-file, so now I'm a bit confused on how I can fix this?

Comment: `HelloWorld.cxx` != `HelloWorld.cpp`

Comment: Ah thanks! It works now. I'm just going to assume that you always have to create the build-directory first.